# How to handle AWS Amplify Web App Security?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

If I am using AWS Amplify & DynamoDB with an Angular web app, how do I restrict access to my Amplify resources so that they’re not able to be accessed from outside of my Angular application?

The primary vulnerability would seem to be that my Amplify config is exposed in the Angular code. I want to eliminate the ability for a malicious developer to take this config and develop some bot or hack app.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to the below response. Question still completely unanswered. Seems like you haven't used Amplify if you can't understand how Amplify is configured on a client.

You create an amplify config and then you instantiate Amplify in your client, even if you use .env or any other client side secrets management, your process.env will still be exposed.

Which means any rogue developer could grab your User Pool ID, Identity Pool ID, and region and recreate your Amplify instance.

This is an actual concern.

Comment: Is there any way to protect user pool ID being exposed?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question (I'm on the fence about whether it's too broad for Stack Overflow). But here goes:

Protecting your (private) resources will require your website to have *authentication* (authN), and possibly also *authorization* (authZ). [Check out this explanation of these concepts](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/authz-and-authn):

> In simple terms, authentication is the process of verifying who a user is, while authorization is the process of verifying what they have access to.

I say you *might* need authZ because in the case where all users are allowed to do everything, then you might do both in the authN step.

---

The most common pattern of achieving this using Amplify is to use [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/). Cognito has two main parts:

**Cognito User Pools**: handle authN. They are a repository of user identities, and Amplify uses them to get *authentication tokens*. They can outsource their real work of authentication to a 3rd-party *Identity Provider*, such as Google or Facebook.

**Cognito Identity Pools**: handle authZ. They are a mapping from user identities (bundled together in a user pool) to *IAM credentials*.

Cognito ID pools are not needed **if** you use [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) which can provide authZ directly from authentication tokens.

---

> The primary vulnerability would seem to be that my Amplify config is exposed in the Angular code

This is a fundamental part of web development. Your front-end must always know which endpoints to use to authenticate and authorize. The trick here is that the endpoints are only useful if the user has credentials to authenticate. This is exactly the behavior of every login page on the web: anyone can *try* to log in to any public login page. But if you the user don't have credentials, the endpoint refuses to authenticate you.

In terms of *other* configuration, if you really want to you can wait until after authN/authZ to provide the front-end with information about where to find its resources such as Dynamo. But this might well be overkill; you should weigh carefully how paranoid you are, to determine whether it's worth hiding the identity of back-end resources which unauthorized users won't be able to access, anyway.

---

Edit in response to comments:

> Can't a developer create an account through my app, use my Amplify config in their own app, authenticate with the account they created through my app, then have free range to my Amplify resources given they're authenticated?

Yup! A simpler way to do this is to authenticate to your app, take the resulting credentials, and use them directly via the console to manually execute operations. But again, this is a fundamental limitation of the client-server interaction: anything you give the front-end (including credentials) can be used in any way the front-end wants, because *you can't control the front-end*. The way around this is to limit the permissions you grant the user **on the back-end**: by strictly limiting the operations which credentials authorize the user to perform.

Another way of thinking about this is that even if you could prevent the user from using the credentials outside of your specific front-end page, they could script a bot to manually click buttons or input garbage. Because you can't control what actions the user will attempt, the only thing you can do is make sure they only succeed doing the things you want them to, by setting permissions accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realize my question is broader and more conceptual than a typical Stack Overflow question, but I can't wrap my ahead around this. I understand the concepts you've brought up around authentication/authorization - thank you for taking the time to lay them out. However, the vulnerability I'm trying to articulate seems to still be unanswered. Can't a developer create an account through my app, use my Amplify config in their own app, authenticate with the account they created through my app, then have free range to my Amplify resources given they're authenticated?

Comment: Thank you again! A script being run against my own app seems less concerning because the operations are bound to what my app provides. My app won't provide the ability for any user to update the ID of a database record, but it will allow multiple users to update other properties of a record. If a malicious dev were to authenticate and gain access to my resources, there seems to be nothing preventing them from updating something I do not want them to update, like an ID - unless I was able, and it was realistic, to write granular rules around which database fields can be updated by which users.

Comment: I guess the root of my question is if developing something like a public social network inherently requires developing a custom backend layer rather than being able to directly leverage some BAAS solution like Amplify or Firebase from my client-side code. Are these BAAS solutions more realistic for certain types of apps, whereas it's not realistic for what I am trying to do? It seems to some extent that my concern should be shared by any developer leveraging these solutions from their frontend.

Comment: To your first point: yes. You're limited by the granularity of IAM policy permissions, which differ between resources, and *yes*, anyone who gets ahold of the credentials will have that level of granularity. You arrive at the correct solution: use a backend layer (an API), and grant permissions on the API. Lastly: these BAAS solutions are libraries like any other, and will never support every possible use-case. Amplify gives you [Storage](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) which does something similar to what you're asking, but for S3. Use the parts that are useful to you :)